# Automatically adding a link on column B to a string in column A in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a simple spreadsheet where one column has a String *(It's a title of a page)* and the other one has a URL of that page:

[image]

I simply want a function to automate adding the link the title as below since I have thousands of them:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: you can do this with the HYPERLINK function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the documentation on the [`HYPERLINK`](https://support.office.com/article/hyperlink-function-333c7ce6-c5ae-4164-9c47-7de9b76f577f) function.

[image: img]

In the example, the formula in `D3` is `=HYPERLINK(C3,B3)`.

Since the information of both Columns `B` and `C` are contained in the hyperlink, those columns no longer need to be visible (so they can be hidden).

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    LastRow = Sheet4.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To LastRow
        With Sheet4
            .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Range("A" & i), Address:= _
            .Range("A" & i).Offset(0, 1).Value, TextToDisplay:=.Range("A" & i).Value
            .Range("A" & i).Offset(0, 1).Value = "" '<= Remove address from the second column
        End With
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: `Range("A" & i)` should be `.Range("A" & i)`

Comment: @Jeeped Done but i think it works without the "."what is your opinion?

Comment: Only if Sheet4 is the active sheet or that code is in Sheet4's private code sheet.